# After enabling ACL's, replication factor errrors in cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, openshift, acl, confluent-platform, sasl

I set up a single node cluster on openshift with SASL_SSL and ACL's. Until I enabled ACL's everything worked fine, the moment I configured ACL this is what I see:

For a "normal" user with ACL's indeed I get topic authorization error, but for super user, I get  :

```
[INFO] 2024-01-11 09:31:25,628 [data-plane-kafka-request-handler-3] kafka.server.ZkAdminManager info - [Admin Manager on Broker 0]: Error processing create topic request CreatableTopic(name='topic_53', numPartitions=1, replicationFactor=1, assignments=[], configs=[], linkName=null, mirrorTopic=null, sourceTopicId=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA, mirrorStartOffsetSpec=-9223372036854775808, mirrorStartOffsets=[])
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0.
```

These are YAMLs that I used:

```
apiVersion: platform.confluent.io/v1beta1
kind: Zookeeper
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
spec:
  replicas: 1
  storageClass:
    name: nfs-client
  license:
    globalLicense: true   
  image:
    application: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.5.0
    init: confluentinc/confluent-init-container:2.7.0
  dataVolumeCapacity: 10Gi
  logVolumeCapacity: 10Gi
  tls:
    autoGeneratedCerts: true
  podTemplate:
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 256Mi
    podSecurityContext: {}

---

apiVersion: platform.confluent.io/v1beta1
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: aclkafka
spec:
  replicas: 1
  storageClass:
    name: nfs-client
  license:
    globalLicense: true  
  tls:
    autoGeneratedCerts: true
  listeners:
    internal:
      tls:
        enabled: true      
    external:
      tls:
        enabled: true
      authentication:
        type: plain
        jaasConfig:
          secretRef: credential  
      externalAccess:
        type: route
        route:
          domain: apps.ocp.tangram-soft.com 
          brokerPrefix: aclbroker 
  image:
    application: confluentinc/cp-server:7.5.0
    init: confluentinc/confluent-init-container:2.7.0
  dataVolumeCapacity: 10Gi
  configOverrides: 
    server:
      - "authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer"
      - "confluent.license.topic.replication.factor=1"
      - "confluent.metrics.reporter.topic.replicas=1"
      - "confluent.tier.metadata.replication.factor=1"
      - "confluent.metadata.topic.replication.factor=1"
      - "confluent.balancer.topic.replication.factor=1"
      - "confluent.security.event.logger.exporter.kafka.topic.replicas=1"
      - "event.logger.exporter.kafka.topic.replicas=1"
      - "offsets.topic.replication.factor=1"
      - "confluent.cluster.link.enable=true"
      - "password.encoder.secret=secret"
      - "auto.create.topics.enable=true"
  authorization:
    type: simple
    superUsers:
    - User:alex
  podTemplate:
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 200m
        memory: 512Mi
    podSecurityContext: {}  
  metricReporter:
    enabled: true
    bootstrapEndpoint: aclkafka:9071
    tls:
      enabled: true
  dependencies:
    zookeeper:
      endpoint: zookeeper:2182
      tls:
        enabled: true
```

Any ideas what am I missing?

Thank you in advance.